# Error 191 while sharing using javascript in Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am creating pagetab app for facebook, while sharing the content to facebook it show the following error.

```
An error occurred. Please try again later.

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.
```

I am using the following code

```
FB.ui({
   method: 'feed',
   name: 'Jag har blivit mÃ¥nadsgivare hos Hundstallet!',
   caption: '',
   description: (
              'Hundstallet hjÃ¤lper hundar som farit illa till ett lyckligt ' +
                              'och tryggt liv. HjÃ¤lp dem du med!'
                       ),
   link: '<?php echo $pageTabUrl;?>',
   picture: 'https://hundstallet.tas.se/monthlydonor/images/share.jpg'
   },
   function(response) {
               if (response && response.post_id) {
                     // alert('Post was published.');
                   } else {
                     // alert('Post was not published.');
                   }
   }
              );
```

If I create a canvaspage app in the facebook developers area with the same url to that pagetab url, the sharing works fine but if I delete the canvaspage app and only keep pagetab app there it shows the above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fill the address into "Website with Facebook Login" => Site URL

add your domain to "App Domains"

You will not be able to save if you skip the first step